# Node.js - Handling hundreds of user preferences

Tags: node.js, socket.io, multi-user, socket.io-1.0

I'm learning node.js (my web background is mainly PHP) and I'm loving it so far but I have the following question. In PHP and other similar languages, each request is a single lived execution of the script. All user preferences can be loaded, etc can be loaded and there's no issue there as once the script execution has been completed, all resources will be released.

In node.js, especially in a long running process like a chatroom (I'm using socket.io), you will have hundreds/thousands of users being handled by one process. Assuming for instance I have a chatroom with 200 people, and I want messages to be highlighted if it comes from a participant the user has deemed a "Friend", then I will have to loop through 200 users to see if the user is a friend or not (especially if chats are to be only sent to friends and not publicly).

Won't this be really slow, especially over time? Is there something I'm missing out on? In my small tests as the number of users as well as number of messages go up, the responsiveness of the server goes down noticeably.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to develop a complex chatroom, you have to consider design the server side code and maintain the clients information at the server side. For example, you have to map the newly connected client socket to variables at the server side, also if you want to introduce "Friend" feature you have to maintain those information at server side. So your server don't have to look up each client see if they are the correct message receivers.

With all those implemented, in the scenario of sending message to the public, at the server side we could first find all the "friend" sockets, then send the message highlighted as "Friend" to those sockets, then send normal text to others. For private message to Friend, it will be much easier as we only consider friends sockets.

So you still need to reuse some of your design patterns you've used in PHP, socket.io would only maintain the long connections for you, and that is all.